# Using the YUI2 paginator widget with a YUI3 data table

Tags: javascript, yui, yahoo

Has anybody used the `Yahoo User Interface 3 (YUI3)` data table with the `YUI2 paginator widget`?  I am looking for samples can't find any?  Is it is wise choice to use it like this or is there something else that can be used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here's an [example](http://jafl.github.com/yui3-gallery/querybuilder/) of a YUI3 paginator on a datatable which a created in YUI3 as an  unofficial port of YUI2 Paginator, and you can download it and look at documentation [here](http://yuilibrary.com/gallery/show/paginator).